# Can not fetch hibernate object attribute within ObjectList - java.lang.String cannot be cast to Object

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces

I have the following Hibernate Object implemented:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imageviewer_crvariable")
public class CRVariable implements Serializable   {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "VarId")
private Long varId;

@Column(name = "VarName")
private String varName;

@Column(name = "VarDescription")
private String varDescription;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="crvariables")
private Set<CRImageType> crimagetypes = new HashSet<CRImageType>();

public CRVariable(){
}

public CRVariable(Long varId,String varName, String varDescription){
    this.varId=varId;
    this.varName=varName;
    this.varDescription=varDescription;
}

//getters and setters
```

I have also a primefaces picklist component which is managed by a back bean. I have implemented a method "setAssocImTypeVariables" which updates my hibernate object (CRVariable) with new picklist values (after list items transfer from source to target) as follows:

```
public void setAssocImTypVariables() {      
    dualListVars = getDualListVars();       
    List<CRVariable> sourceVariables = dualListVars.getSource();
    List<CRVariable> targetVariables = dualListVars.getTarget();

    for (int i=0; i<sourceVariables.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a source variable: " + sourceVariables.get(i));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<targetVariables.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: " + targetVariables.get(i));
    }

    CRImageType selectedImageType = getSelectedCRImageType();
    Long selImTypeId = selectedImageType.getImTypeId();
```

This code works fine and here are the results i get in my console:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a source variable: varId : 75, varName : Ki67(X), varDescription : Ki67(X)
>>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a source variable: varId : 76, varName : PTEN(X), varDescription : PTEN(X)
>>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a source variable: varId : 77, varName : Histology (X), varDescription : Histology (X)
>>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: varId : 72, varName : HER2(X), varDescription : HER2(X)
>>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: varId : 71, varName : ER (X), varDescription : ER (X)
>>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: varId : 74, varName : FISH, varDescription : FISH description
```

But when i try to get VarId for each one of the Objects of  targetVariables List, as:

```
System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: " + targetVariables.get(i).getVarId());
```

i get the following error:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: varId : 72, varName : HER2(X), varDescription : HER2(X)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.forth.dbutils.CRVariable
    at com.forth.actions.ReportConfiguratorBean.setAssocImTypVariables(ReportConfiguratorBean.java:414)
```

The line 414 is the one i am trying to get VarId property for current object list: **targetVariables.get(i).getVarId()**:

```
 System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: " + targetVariables.get(i).getVarId());
```

Any ideas about what is wrong in my Hibernate object implementation???

Comment: Can you show exact code in Line 414

Comment: I have just re-entered the line (see edited post above) ... I am intenting to use VarId in an SQL query but first i have to fetch it!

Comment: System out targetVariables.get(i).getClass().getName() . Is it CRVariable type?

Comment: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.forth.dbutils.CRVariable .... So i guess it is...

Comment: After some research targetVariables.get(i) returns a STRING and not an object of type CRVariable.

Comment: Problem seems to be the absense of a Converter for primefaces picklist object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My picklist component:

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" 
  value="#   {reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}"
  var="cRVariable" 
  itemValue="#{cRVariable}" 
  itemLabel="#{cRVariable.varName}"
  converter="cRVariableConverter"
  Ajax="false" >
  <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available Variables</f:facet>
  <f:facet name="targetCaption">Associated Variables</f:facet>              
</p:pickList>
```

And the cRVariableConverter in order to get CRVariable target list items as Objects:

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Long varId = Long.parseLong(value.trim());  
    List<CRVariable> cRVariables = mybean.getCRVariables();

    for (CRVariable cRVariable:cRVariables) {
        if(cRVariable.getVarId().compareTo(varId)==0){
            return cRVariable;
        }
    }

    return null;    
}
```